# MS Visual Studio 2022 Возможно ли отобразить окно программы при точке останова

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Отлаживаю приложение Windows Forms в MS Visual Studio 2022. При попадании в точку останова хотелось бы увидеть внешний вид окна приложения: сейчас оно становится свёрнутым.

Comment: Есть одна особенность, которая в некотором роде позволяет добиться желаемого результата:

Comment: если установить свойство формы TopMost в true, то даже при попадании в точку останова окно формы будет "наверху"; однако до продолжения выполнения кода сделать с ней нельзя ничего: ни передвинуть, ни свернуть; таким образом она будет загораживать окно IDE, что затрудняет работу.

Comment: В коде на C# можно сделать: `if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) { this.Topmost = true; }` чтобы `Topmost` включалось только в отладке